# .Net Core OfficeOpenXml создание excel файла из коллекции типизированной базовым классом

Tags: c#, excel, .net-core, epplus

```
class Product
{
    public int Id {get:set;}
}

class Car : Product
{
   public string Name {get;set;}
}

var products = new List<Product>();
var car = new Car();
products.Add(car);
```

Потом из *products* создаю excel файл, но в нем нет поля *Name*. Избавится от восходящего преобразования проблематично. Можно ли с помощью *OfficeOpenXml* получить адекватный результат?

---

Такая же проблема с либой [LinqToCsv](https://github.com/frank-lores/LINQtoCSV.Core) .
*System.Xml.Serialization* работает адекватно.

---

Пример кода для воспроизведения:

```
using OfficeOpenXml;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{

    class Program
    {        
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var products = new List<Product>();
            var car = new Car
            {
                Id = 1,
                Name = "лада"
            };
            products.Add(car);

            var plane = new Airplane
            {
                Id = 2,
                Speed = 500
            };
            products.Add(plane);

            var stream = Convert(products);
            var fstream = new FileStream("products.xlsx", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
            stream.WriteTo(fstream);
            stream.Close();
            fstream.Close();
        }

        public static MemoryStream Convert(IEnumerable<Product> collection)
        {
            ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial;
            var result = new MemoryStream();
            using (var pck = new ExcelPackage())
            {
                AddSheet(pck, collection, "машины", typeof(Car));
                AddSheet(pck, collection, "самолеты", typeof(Airplane));

                pck.SaveAs(result);
            }


            return result;
        }

        private static void AddSheet(in ExcelPackage pck, IEnumerable<Product> collection, string sheetName, Type productType)
        {
            var products = collection.Where(p => p.GetType() == productType);
            if (products.FirstOrDefault() != null)
            {
                ExcelWorksheet tyreSheet = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(sheetName);
                var tableRange = tyreSheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromCollection(products, true);
                tableRange.AutoFilter = true;
                tableRange.AutoFitColumns();
            }
        }
    }

    class Product
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }

    class Car : Product
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    class Airplane : Product
    {
        public int Speed { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: То есть у вас проблема в коде, который вы не покажете, я все верно понял? `System.Xml.Serialization работает адекватно` - так используйте, что с этим не так? А вообще в таких случаях избавляются от обобщения, типа `(IEnumerable)products`, но решение зависит от конкретного сериализатора и конкретной структуры данных, поэтому нужен код, который воспроизводит проблему.

Comment: System.Xml.Serialization мне не достаточно, нужны все три. В коде проблемы нет. Проблема с тем, что метод openofficeXml.LoadFromCollection не вытаскивает из коллекции типизированной базовым типом, ее реальные производные объекты.

Comment: var tableRange = tyreSheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromCollection(products, true); Вот кусок моего кода, в коллекции products находятся объекты типа Car

Comment: Потому что вы обобщенный метод используете и обобщенную коллекцию, так себя ведут много сериализаторов. Нужен воспроизводимый пример. Напишите простое консольное приложение, которое использует нужный вам сериализатор, в результате работы которого получается неверный результат. Опубликуйте код в самом вопросе. Запущу, проверю, попробую исправить.

Comment: выложил пример кода для воспроизведения. Желательно чтобы структура и сигнатура методов сохранилась в том виде в каком она в примере.

Comment: Общая задача стоит такая: в зависимости от настроек в каждом отдельном случае используем один из трех форматов: excel , csv, xml и один из двух протоколов: smtp, ftp. Также могут быть не все виды продуктов. Реализовал все на основе полиморфизма. Но столкнулся с такой проблемой. Не хотелось бы переписывать всю реализацию полотном из if then else :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данный конкретный случай можно решить вот так:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var products = new List<Product>();
    var car = new Car
    {
        Id = 1,
        Name = "лада"
    };
    products.Add(car);

    var plane = new Airplane
    {
        Id = 2,
        Speed = 500
    };
    products.Add(plane);

    using (var ms = Convert(products))
    using (var fs = File.Create("products.xlsx"))
    {
        ms.WriteTo(fs);
    }
    Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo { FileName = "products.xlsx", UseShellExecute = true });
}

public static MemoryStream Convert(IEnumerable<Product> collection)
{
    ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial;
    var result = new MemoryStream();
    using (var pck = new ExcelPackage())
    {
        AddSheet(pck, collection.OfType<Car>(), "машины");
        AddSheet(pck, collection.OfType<Airplane>(), "самолеты");

        pck.SaveAs(result);
    }

    return result;
}

private static void AddSheet<T>(in ExcelPackage pck, IEnumerable<T> collection, string sheetName)
{
    if (collection.Any())
    {
        ExcelWorksheet tyreSheet = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(sheetName);
        var tableRange = tyreSheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromCollection(collection, true);
        tableRange.AutoFilter = true;
        tableRange.AutoFitColumns();
    }
}
```

То есть использовать непосредственно то обобщение, которое нужно.

Comment: Спасибо, это помогло!

Comment: @Vasiliy для красоты можно еще у MemoryStream сбрасывать маркер на начало `result.Position = 0`, и записывать через `.CopyTo`. А еще лучше сразу в целевой поток. Мне показалось, оно что-то не быстро отрабатывает.